# Angular 1 big data for $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest issue

Tags: angularjs, ajax, request, response

I have a strange situation when the ajax data is big I can get only part of them, each time the part is the same. All is good for small data, but when uploading data is big more (77 rows from excel spreadsheet, each row has 8 column) the response only 77 items. The strange situation happens inside $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest. Please help.

My code is a

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    /**
 * The workhorse; converts an object to x-www-form-urlencoded serialization.
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @return {String}
 */
var param = function(obj) {
    var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

    for(name in obj) {
        value = obj[name];

        if(value instanceof Array) {
            for(i=0; i<value.length; ++i) {
                subValue = value[i];
                fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
                innerObj = {};
                innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                query += param(innerObj) + '&';
            }
        }
        else if(value instanceof Object) {
            for(subName in value) {
                subValue = value[subName];
                fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
                innerObj = {};
                innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
                query += param(innerObj) + '&';
            }
        }
        else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
            query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
        else if(value == null)
            query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + '&';
    }

    return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
};
   // Override $http service's default transformRequest
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {
    return angular.isObject( data ) && String( data ) !== '[object File]' ? angular.toParam( data ) : data;
}];
```

Updated.
I have found like this solution but here I lost that column name=>values which are null:

```
 .config(function($httpProvider, $httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider){
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift($httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider.$get());})
```

As you can see earlier we have checked value for null situation

```
else if(value == null)
            query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + '&';
```

But still need help to get all null items like ""

**Solved**
I have increased max_input_vars = 5000 from php.ini